# How to add a google script trigger that runs every hour near minute 15?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is what I've tried

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
.timeBased()
.everyHours(1).nearMinute(15)
.create();
```

But it doesn't run near minute 15.

Later Edit:
It seems to be working as expected. I'm leaving this open just in case someone else needs it.

Per the comments, it appears the reported time of execution is listing the time the script completes.  So beginning near the 15 minute mark, yet completing at the 17 minute mark.

Comment: When does it run?

Comment: It seems to run at minute 17 of every hour, but I figured it out that it adds the elapsed time of function execution.

Answer (score 0):

try everyHours()

ie

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
.timeBased()
.everyHours().nearMinute(15)
.create();
```

Comment: It says `method everyHours()`